# Android;communication between content provider and remote service

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-contentprovider

I have a **content provider** and **remote service**.Clients query content provider to find user data and remote service tries to fetch data from web server.I know how to bind content provider to service,but I do not know how to return data from query method of content provider.These lines may explain my plan:

1- client query from content provider.
2- content provider creates a `ServiceConnection`and passes it to service to bind.
3- service starts `AsyncTask` and fetch data.
4- data add to `Binder` and can retrieved in content provider.
5- data is available in content provider ........ but ...

But how I can return retrieved  data as response of `query` method of content provider to client?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira suppose response is text and can convert to JSON. But what you mean?

Comment: oh i see what you mean. you need to get result from service?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira yes.